# Detect Whatsapp image upload source

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, whatsapi, infobip, infobip-api

I am building an official Whatsapp channel for customer support. I am using Infobip messaging services and I want to identify two things from a whatsapp message:

1. If the image uploaded by a Whatsapp user on an official whatsapp channel was taken in real time using Whatsapp camera or not?
2. If not then what is the source of image taken i.e is it gallery, google photos etc.

I tried google but could not find anything relevant. Any help with web links, blogs, doc, books are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.